# Convert dynamic formula as text into a working formula in Excell

Tags: excel

I have the following Dynamic formula build as text, and I need it to work as a real formula:

"=HLOOKUP(M3;Sheet1!L3:P3;1;FALSE)"

when I use it as real formula in a cell it works but i need to work as a textformula.

I have constructed the dynamic formula as text, but am stuck converting the string into a working formula. I've tried the eval(formula as string), but that does not work. However (eval("1+1") works).

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try building the formula components using "INDIRECT" or have you done any VBA before?

Comment: Where did you get "EVAL" from? I created my own EVAL udfunction `Public Function Eval(t As String)      
Eval = Evaluate(t)      
End Function` and it works fine

Comment: I just tried using your eval function...but still snot working. In the cell the i place the =eval(mystringformula) i see the the warning " a value used in the formula is of the wrong datatype"

Comment: Aren't parameters supposed to be separated with commas, not semi-colons? e.g. `HLOOKUP(M3,Sheet1` etc. instead of `HLOOKUP(M3;Sheet1` etc.

Comment: when i enter the formula as formula, in my excel i have to use semi-colons. =HLOOKUP(M3;Sheet1!L3:P3;1;FALSE) works when entered as a formula in a cell, it retrieves the correct value

Comment: Thanks for the help, i've used the INDIRECT option to create my dynamic formula.

Comment: Sorry I was meant to come back to this question, I used to use INDIRECT quite often to build up filenames, formulae etc. It's very handy.